# Can't access foreignKey in template

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to access a foreignKey object in my template, but it doesn't show anything at all.

I'd like to show the url to the ImageField saved in the db

Models.py

```
class Usertasks(models.Model):
    TaskID = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    TaskStatus = models.CharField(max_length=15, default="missing")

class TaskImages(models.Model):
    UserTasks = models.ForeignKey(Usertasks, related_name='images', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField()
```

views.py

```
def task_info(request, taskid):
    task = Usertasks.objects.get(TaskID=taskid)
    taskhtml = Usertasks.objects.filter(TaskID=taskid)
    files = os.listdir(task.OutputPath)
    fullpath = task.OutputPath
    print(files)
    for img in files:
        imagepath = fullpath + "/" + img
        task_image = TaskImages()
        task_image.UserTasks = task
        task_image.image = imagepath
        task_image.save()
    return render(request, 'dashboard/task.html', {'query':taskhtml})
```

html

```
{% for item in query.image_set.all %}

<img src="{{ item.url }}">

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The `query` contains a set of `Usertaks`, not a single one, hence `query.image_set`, makes no sense.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem How would I go on then? The main thing is that I need to filter a specific task ID and then show all related ImageFields to that Task ID in the template.

Comment: use `.get(..)` instead of `.filter(..)`

Comment: I exchanged the `{'query':taskhtml}` with `{'query':task}` which uses the `.get(..)` , but it still doesn't render anything in my template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the `related_name` kwarg set for `UserTasks` in `TaskImages`.  Therefore you use that value in place for `_set`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

> You can override the FOO_set name by setting the related_name parameter in the ForeignKey definition.

For your issue, you'd need to use `query.images`, rather than `image_set`